# ListView populates but each view is blank at first?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-arrayadapter

I'm using a ListView inside a Fragment which downloads notes from Firebase storage and then displays them. However, the problem I'm running into is when it displays the notes its just a empty note layout, but when I switch activities and go back they're no longer blank, they're loaded. I'm not sure where exactly I'm going wrong, I've tried calling onDataSetChange to the Adapter Everywhere, also tried invalidate() and invalidateViews() on the ListView hoping it would just simply refresh the views, but unfortunately that didnt work either :/ the code is below, thank you in advanced for any help! :)

this is where I'm setting the Adapter in my Notes fragment

```
mNoteStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("Notes").child(currentUser.getUid());
    mNotesDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            my_notes.setAdapter(null);
            Iterable<DataSnapshot> all_keys = dataSnapshot.getChildren();
            filename_arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
            na = null;
            for (DataSnapshot each_key : all_keys) {
                String each = each_key.getKey();
                filename_arrayList.add(each);
            }
            for (String each_filename : filename_arrayList) {
                downloadFile(each_filename);
                Note each_note = Utilities.getNoteByName(getContext(), each_filename + Utilities.FileExtention);
                each_note_array.add(each_note);
            }

            if (each_note_array == null || each_note_array.size() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "No Notes!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                na = new MyNotesAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.item_note, each_note_array);
                my_notes.setAdapter(na);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

and Here's my Adapter

```
class MyNotesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Note> {

Context ctx;

public MyNotesAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Note> note) {
    super(context, resource, note);

    this.ctx = context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    //return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_note, null);
    }

    Note note = getItem(position);

    if(note != null) {
        TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_note_title);
        TextView content = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_note_content);
        TextView date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_note_date);

        Typeface music_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/melodymakernotesonly.ttf");
        Typeface scribble_card = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/the unseen.ttf");

        if (getThemeCountInt() == 0) {
            title.setTypeface(music_font);
        } else if (getThemeCountInt() == 1) {
            title.setTypeface(scribble_card);
        }

        content.setTypeface(scribble_card);

        title.setText(note.getTitle());
        date.setText(note.getDateTimeFormatted(getContext()));

        if(note.getContent().length() > 25) {
            content.setText(note.getContent().substring(0,25) + "...");
        } else {
            content.setText(note.getContent());
        }

        if(note.getContent().length() <= 0) {
            content.setText("(Empty Note..)");
        } else {
            content.setText(note.getContent());
        }

        if (note.getTitle().length() <= 0) {
            title.setText("(Untitled)");
        } else {
            title.setText(note.getTitle());
        }
    }

    return convertView;
}

private int getThemeCountInt() {
    SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences = this.getContext().getSharedPreferences("theme", MODE_PRIVATE);
    int selectedTheme = mSharedPreferences.getInt("theme", 0);
    return selectedTheme;

}
```

}

downloadFile

```
private void downloadFile(final String filenames) {


    final String each_filename = filenames + Utilities.FileExtention;
    final long file_size = 1024 * 1024;
        mNoteStorage.child(each_filename).getBytes(file_size).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<byte[]>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(byte[] bytes) {
                FileOutputStream stream;
                FileInputStream streamIn;
                    try {
                        File dir = getActivity().getApplication().getFilesDir();
                        File file = new File(dir, each_filename);

                        stream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        stream.write(bytes);

                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }
        });
}
```

Utilities.getNoteByName

```
public static Note getNoteByName(Context context, String filename) {
    File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), filename);
    Note note;

    if (file.exists()) {
        FileInputStream fis;
        ObjectInputStream ois;

        try {
            fis = context.openFileInput(filename);
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

            note = (Note) ois.readObject();

            fis.close();
            ois.close();

        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

        return note;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After you create `MyNotesAdapter` call `notifyDataSetChanged()` method to let `ListView` instance knows that underlying data has changed.

```
my_notes.setAdapter(na);
na.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Personally I prefer to create and set adapter instance once and then use its `add()` method to manipulate its underlying data. Once I finished, I call adapter `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Recreating new adapter instance each time database change may trigger garbage collector to run more often.

Comment: I've tried this many times, it just doesn't seem to be working like i'd expected :/ when I call notifyDataSetChanged(); it loads empty views, like if there's 3 notes it loads 3 empty viewholders for the notes but doesn't display any information :/ im guessing this might be a problem with my adapter, but the weird thing is when i reload the page it loads the notes correctly, even if i rotate the screen it loads all the info. just not on the first start of the activity :/

Comment: If your view holder looks empty make sure that `note` in `getView()` not null. Try to remove conditional check. If it throws null pointer exception then that is cause of empty view holder

Comment: Yes, this is exactly whats causing it. I'm not sure why but it seems that getItem(position) is returning null until i refresh the activity. I've tried everything I can think of lol and I'm pretty sure my ArrayList isn't empty when i set the adapter.

Comment: `Utilities.getNoteByName()` somehow returns null. Make sure you add note to array list only if they are not null.

Comment: Ohh that makes sense, but if my ArrayList was empty would it still load them when I refresh the activity?

Comment: I think it has something to do with my downloadFile not finishing before filling the ArrayList and setting the adapter, I'm still very new to Android so please excuse my ignorance. I added the downloadFile function to see if maybe I'm doing something wrong there

Comment: So I've tried everything.. I put my DownloadFile function into an AsyncTask and moved it into the activity instead of the fragment. I even tried refreshing the fragment onPostExecute() and no luck with anything :/ my Utilities.getNoteByName is still returning null..until I refresh the activity